# Procedure or Function 'ValidateUserLogin' expects parameter '@UserName', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have this stored procedure for validating login

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ValidateUserLogin
(
@UserName varchar (50),
@Password varchar (50)
)
AS
BEGIN
if EXISTS(SELECT * FROM AdminLogin WHERE UserName=@UserName AND Password=@Password)
select 0/*returns 0 on success*/
ELSE
select 1/*non zero otherwise*/

END
```

and i am calling it using the code below but i get the following exception "Procedure or Function 'ValidateUserLogin' expects parameter '@UserName', which was not supplied."

```
   bool boolReturnValue = true;

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = sqlConnection;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "ValidateUserLogin";
    command.Parameters.Add(@username,SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value=username;
    command.Parameters.Add(@password, SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value=password;
    sqlConnection.Open();
    try
    {
    command.ExecuteScalar();
       boolReturnValue=Convert.ToBoolean( command.ExecuteScalar());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
```

and when i try to set default value for the username and password as null i get the exception
@admin is not a parameter for procedure ValidateUserLogin
//admin is the value provided for username

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the following two lines:

```
command.Parameters.Add(@username,SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value=username;
command.Parameters.Add(@password, SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value=password;
```

with:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Username",SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value=username;
command.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value=password;
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that SQL stored procedures are case sensitive? I thought not

Comment: @nuux - This depends upon the default collation of the database. Most people don't have CS collations. But the lack of quotes on the first version will definitely cause a problem as it will try and submit parameters named after what ever the value of the variables happens to be. This should have `"@UserName"` to address both possible issues.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Sorry I'vent noticed the quoatation. When possiby can someone have CS collations

Comment: @nuuk - It's just an option you can set at the instance or database level. I develop on a CS collation so my code will work regardless of whether it is used on a case sensitive or insensitive one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your parameter name in quotes for the Add method. In other words, "@username" with the quotes.

Comment: +1 Without the quotes it is not a string and just refers to the variable `username` (The `@` prefix is optionally allowed there to allow reserved words as variable names IIRC)

Answer (score 1):

If your database is case sensitive than the parameters have case sensitivity

```
 command.Parameters.Add(@username,SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value=username;
```

should have @UserName parameter to match the procedure's case.

Same applies for password of course.

Comment: That was so useful and it actually solved my problem..I always considered @variable is the reference to my variable.Thanx alot